# Is there a way to force Modernizr to load scripts synchroneous (I need it to block)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, modernizr

this might be a strange question but I'm having a problem and I can fix it but I'm just wondering if there is a more elegant way. Basicly, I need to know if I can make modernizr.load() work synchroneous instead of asynchroneous.

the code looks like this (semi-pseudo code ahead) ...

---

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="modernizr-with-yepnope.js">

<script>
  var App = {};
  (function($)) {
    $(function() {
      initAllAppMethods();
    });
  })(jQuery);
 </script>

 <script>
   modernizr.load([
     {
       test: 'window.matchmedia',
       nope: 'polyfillmatchmedia.js'
     },
     'script.js'
     ]);
 </script>
```

**SCRIPT.JS**

```
 <script>
   App.myAppmethod = function() {
     // ...
   }
 </script>
```

---

Now, the problem I'm having is that due to the asynchroneous nature of modernizr.load, the $.ready function fires before my App methods are actually added to the App object (or at least that's what I think is the problem). So in essence nothing happens as the App doesn't have any methods yet when $.ready fires.

Now, this can easily be fixed by calling initAllAppMethods() at the end in scripts.js but that just hides the problem of the load order. The reason script.js needs to be loaded by modernizr.load() is because it needs to know if the polyfill is active.

So ... for anyone reading this far ... if you are wondering why I'm not loading everything through modernizr.load(), it's because I'm kinda bound to this order due to the CMS in which I'm implementing this. If I could make modernizr.load() load scripts.js synchroneous there would be no problem. (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than load all of them, use the 'complete' method of yepnope (what `Modernizr.load` uses under the  hood)

```
modernizr.load([{
 load: {
      test: 'window.matchmedia',
      nope: 'polyfillmatchmedia.js'
    },
   'script.js': true
 },
 complete: function() {$.ready(
    //...
 )}
 ]);
```